# My Model is not called when page loads

Tags: ember.js

when new page loades I am trying to fetch data in my `route` but I am not getting any response from my `model` method. rest of all other methods called. what is wrong here?

here is my code :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model(params){ //not calling
        console.log('got the model', params );
        return this.store.peekRecord('card-list', params.id );
    },

    setupController(controller,model) {//called
        console.log("super")
        this._super(...arguments);
        console.log("model is", controller,"\n", model );
    },

    init(){//called
        console.log("init calledx"); 
    }

});
```

**UPDATE**

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('review');
  this.route('confirmation');

  this.route('cs2i', function() {
    this.route('balance', function() {
      this.route('balanceDetails');
      this.route('balanceEdit', { path: '/balanceEdit/:id' });
      this.route('balanceReview', { path: '/balanceReview/:id' });
    });

    this.route('purchase', function() {
      this.route('purchaseDetails');
      this.route('purchaseEdit');
      this.route('purchaseReview');
    });
  });
```

Comment: Always remember to call `this._super(...arguments)` whenever you override init method.

Comment: Are you passing a model to the transition?

Comment: No I am not passing, but I passing the I'd as parameter

Comment: Can you provide a router.js code for this route?

Comment: @suricatta - router details added for your reference

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I still don't know what the problem is - your code looks fine.